# csv_output containing with field . (full stop)

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I have a php script that is generating a tab delimited .txt file that works great but I need to output a field that contains a . (full stop/ period) within the $model field i.e itemname.1 it affects the formatting of the file.

```
$csv_output .= $model . "\t";
$csv_output .= '' . "\t";
$csv_output .= '' . "\t";
$csv_output .= '' . "\t";
$csv_output .= $totalstock . "\t";
$csv_output .= $leadtime . "\t";
$csv_output .= "\n";

$csv_handler = fopen('../outputfile.txt','w');
fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv_output);
fclose ($csv_handler);
```

I have tried enclosing in double quotes and various other variations but the output is inserting newlines 
example output

```
itemname.1

            20  1
```

any ideas how i can output the fields with the . in them without it affecting the tabs/lines.

Comment: why would `.` affect tabs?

Comment: Any reason you're not using `fputcsv()`?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the full stop. I think `$model` has a newline at the end of it. Try using `trim($model)`.

Comment: Maybe $model is actually itemname.1\r\n ?

Comment: no itemname as nothing after it it is coming from a sql table and i have double checked.
I have a duplicate table without the .1 etc in the itemname and this works fine.
it is deffinatly the . in the $model causing the issue

Comment: @ShaGGy I don't think so, but you can easily test it by replacing `$model` with the literal `'itemname.1'` in your PHP script

Comment: now i'm puzzled in the sql table i have itemname.1 in the model column but if i do a search for itemname.1 it finds no results if i change the entry in mysqladmin to itemname it works nad is searchable?
is this a sql issue?

Comment: just changed itemname.1 to itemname and it worked then changed it back to itemname.1 in myphpadmin and it now works?
looks like the data in the database is causing the issue and not the script.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys after the comments I have looked into it from the bottom up and the original csv file i was given to import into the db appears to have carriage returns in between each line :(
Thanks for all your suggestions it helps me rethink what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us your code that encloses the variable in quotes please?

The not-very-well-informed solution appears to be use replace() to test if the . is indeed causing the new line, or if it's "something else". You might just be able to replace new line straight up even.

Comment: HI Mark it is definatly the . in the field causing it, if i use a sql table that does not have . in the model the output is as expected.
If i rem out the $csv_output .= $model . "\t"; but leave the other columns in place the output is fine also (minus the model number which contained the .'s)

Comment: Ok. Did you try using replace to replace the newline or . chars?

Answer (score 0):

It Was a school boy error.
The issue was the data imported into db had carriage returns on each line entry, although the data appeared correct in the db and in excel the problem only manifested in the output file.
Thanks for your help guys made me go back to source and identify the issue.